# В классе enum есть список значений. Что значат возле каждого из них значения в скобках?

Tags: java, enum

В классе enum есть список значений. Что значат возле каждого из них значения в скобках?

например в `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.ConfigFeature.SerializationFeature`
есть строка `WRITE_BIGDECIMAL_AS_PLAIN(false)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ENUM - это класс,  объекты которой создаются в единственном экземпляре и доступны статически. Тело ENUM может включать методы и другие поля.

```
public enum MyEnum {

    A(true),
    B(false);

    private boolean  key;
    MyEnum(boolean  input) {
        key = input;
    }

    public boolean isTrue() {
        return key;
    }

    public void someMethod(){

   }
}

MyEnum e = MyEnum.A;
System.out.println(e.isTrue()); // true
```

Подробнее можно ознакомиться [тут](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Answer (score 1):

Значения в скобках - значения для конструктора. Вы можете сделать enam с конструктором:

```
public enum Human{
    MAN("ADAM"), //Значения в скобках будут переданы в конструктор
    WOMAN("EVA");

  String name;

  Human(String name){ //Конструктор 
  this.name = name;
 }

   String getName(){ 
    return name;
 }
}

 //где то в коде:
   Human.MAN.getName(); // вернет имя ADAM
```